# c code for gtk+ vs glade generated .glade files

Tags: c, gtk, gtkbuilder

I am new in the field of gtk+ programming. I'm still exploring many options to use. I will be coding in C language. I have the following questions:

1. Which is better? Writing code or using the .glade files generated by glade?
2. Which is better to use? libglade or gtkbuilder?
3. Why is using the build option in glade2 discouraged?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Choose whichever is more convenient for your particular need. Usually people use a Libglade/GtkBuilder file for non-trivial UI (less messy to create and maintain).
2. GtkBuilder is the new, preferred way to do it, and it's part of GTK+. You should only use Libglade if you need to support legacy systems.
3. ["This allows more flexibility with the developer, prevents having to re-compile applications when a minor interface change is needed, and allows more programming languages to be used with Glade."](http://www.micahcarrick.com/gtk-glade-tutorial-part-1.html#Introduction_to_Glade3)

Comment: I wondered wether glade or gtkbuilder was obsolete, thank you for clearing that point +1